# Not understanding a Java polymorphism example involving HashMaps

Tags: java, polymorphism

I'm rusty on my Java polymorphism.

If I have a class Merchandise, and then a class Clothing that extends Merchandise, why aren't I able to do the following?

```
HashMap<String, Merchandise> stuff = new HashMap<String, Clothing>();
```

When I do so, I am getting this compilation error:

```
DataStore.java:5: error: incompatible types: HashMap<String,Clothing> cannot be converted to HashMap<String,Merchandise>
        public static HashMap<String, Merchandise> tshirts = new HashMap<String, Clothing>();
```

Aren't all Clothing items also Merchandise items?
                                                             ^

Comment: what is `Clothing` ? Not a Shoe

Comment: Can you elaborate the classes Clothing and Merchandise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Comment: Yeah, that link is very helpful, Pillar. I just wasn't searching on the right terms to hit it. Sorry for the duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following scenario:

```
HashMap<String, Clothing> clothing = ...
HashMap<String, Merchandise> merchandise = clothing; // Suppose this is allowed
merchandise.put("Potato", new Potato());
```

Uh-oh, by putting potato into merchandise, it has also gone into clothing, because they reference the same object!

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. That make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do like this:
`HashMap<String,? extends merchandise> m=new HashMap<String,Clothing>();`

`HashMap<String, Merchandise>` IS NOT a `HashMap<String, Clothing>()>`.